# Most proper HTML structure to use for parenthetical asides inside a quotation

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

Suppose I have to translate the following blockquote to an HTML markup:

> *The quick brown fox jumped* **(some kind of parenthetical aside)** *over the head of the lazy dog.*

What is the best way to approach structuring the  content? Do I just simply wrap the parenthetical aside above in a `<span>` tag and style it differently like this?

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumped <span class="p-aside">(some kind of parenthetical aside)</span> over the head of the lazy dog.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Or maybe there's something else I can use for this specific case? Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by "remark"? Do you mean like a narrator having some kind of parenthetical aside? A real example would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Sean, I actually meant parenthetical aside now that I searched that term, thanks. I wasn't sure what it was called. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on [how you're using the parentheses](https://writingcenter.uagc.edu/parentheses), but I don't think any special semantic markup is needed here. The parentheses themselves serve to communicate the separateness and change in voice of the aside. If you need to style it differently, a non-semantic `<span>` would be the way to go.

```css
blockquote {
  font-style: italic;
}
.parenthetical-aside {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>She’s been dating Nathan <span class="parenthetical-aside">(the shy twin)</span> for about six months now.</p>
</blockquote>
```

However, an argument could be made that an [`<i>` (idiomatic text element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i) could also be appropriate. These elements are used to communicate "spans of text representing a different quality or mode of text, such as an alternative voice or mood" (among other uses). Just remember than many browsers will style this element in italics by default, so you may need to override that.

```css
blockquote {
  font-style: italic;
}
.parenthetical-aside {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>She’s been dating Nathan <i class="parenthetical-aside">(the shy twin)</i> for about six months now.</p>
</blockquote>
```